# How to use fish on remote servers that have it installed without changing login shell?

Tags: shell, ssh, login, fish

I regularly `ssh` on several different servers, some of which don't have `fish` installed, but many do. I'd like to get `fish` as shell if available (changing midway is always tedious, and you lose the history of what you already typed), but changing the default shell is not a good idea, as:

- there are many different machines that I would need to change;
- on many other I'm logged in through LDAP, and changing my shell as stored on LDAP would break on machines where `fish` is not available;
- in general, as `fish` is not POSIX-sh compatible putting it as default shell may break commands executed by scripts through `ssh`;
- finally, there are a few machines where the user is shared with other people (or, where I have to login another user), so changing the default shell is not a good idea.

So, ideally I'd like to have a command like `ssh` that automagically starts `fish` if available, or just leave whatever default shell is provided otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experiments, I put together the `fissh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh "$@" -t "sh -c 'if which fish >/dev/null ; then exec fish -li; else exec \$SHELL -li; fi'"
```

- `"$@"` forwards all arguments passed to `ssh`
- `-t` forces the allocation of a tty (otherwise `ssh` defaults to no tty when a command is specified)
- `sh -c` is required because we don't know what shell we may have on the other side - on my personal machines I do have `fish` as default shell, which would break on the different `if` syntax;
- `which fish` succeeds if it finds an executable `fish`; in that case, it is `exec`-ed (asking for an interactive and login shell);
- otherwise, we fall back to `$SHELL`, which is the default shell for the current user (`$` is escaped otherwise it gets expanded by `sh` "on this side").

`-li` is passed in either case, to make sure that we actually get a *l*ogin *i*nteractive shell. While `-i` is mandated by POSIX for any shell, `-l` is "just" a common extension, but not putting it in is likely to result in bad surprises.

Notice that `stdout` of `which` is hidden (as in the normal case we don't care about where `fish` was found), but `stderr` (where the error message that `fish` couldn't be found) is intentionally left intact as a warning to the user that, despite our best intentions, `fish` couldn't be found.

To complete the experience, on my machines with `fish` I add the support for customized completion by creating a `~/.config/fish/completions/fissh.fish` file containing

```
complete -c fissh -w ssh
```

to instruct `fish` that `fissh` has the exact same valid completions as `ssh`.

Comment: You might want to `exec fish -li` to be explicit.

Comment: @glennjackman: good idea, and I think that should work for any `$SHELL` as well, right?

Comment: *Any* shell? The popular shells, yes probably.

Comment: @glennjackman: just checked, POSIX requires `-i` from `sh`, but not `-l`; I'll play it safe and add it just to `fish`.

Answer (score 0):

This (untested) little expect script would do, I think, the same thing:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh {*}$argv
expect {
    {yes/no}   {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
    -re {\$ $} {send "which fish >/dev/null && exec fish -li\r"}
}
interact
```

Assumptions:

- your login shell is bourne like, and understands "cmd1 && cmd2",
- you don't need to provide a password to log in ,
- your prompt ends with a dollar sign and a space.

Comment: Unfortunately there are cases where assumptions 2 and 3 are both broken. On some machines I happen to log in straight as root (I know, I know...), which has a `#` prompt; also, on other machines (my personal work desktop and home PCs in general) I do have `fish` as default shell, so that `&&` won't do.

Comment: I would keep a list of machines on your local machine where you know fish is already your login shell, and a list where it isn't but fish is available. Then you can keep the logic in the script on your local machine. I can't imagine those lists will be hard to maintain.

Comment: The script is to be used on several machines on different networks. Although it itself is being kept synchronized, I'd like to avoid having to maintain extra lists if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays I would recommend using [XXH](https://github.com/xxh/xxh).

Comment: Feels way more magical than I'm comfortable with, especially for something that needs to be reliable, such as ssh access, and which should not pollute the target system. I'll keep my humble script.

Comment: The project's point is to be explicit and contained into a single folder. A quick read of the readme would address your fears.